# How to find multipe class in css file...

Tags: css

I try to ask my question in another way:

taken from a book: "multiple classes:

```
p.testorosso.grassetto {color: red; font-weight: bold;}
```

This rule will apply the styles set to all the elements in which the names of the classes defined in the selector are present (in any order). They will therefore have red text and bold these paragraphs:

```
<p class="grassetto testorosso maiuscolo">..</p>
<p class="testorosso grassetto">...</p>
```

but not this, because only one of the names is present as a class value:

```
<p class="grassetto">...</p> "
```

is this rule correct?

I will write a program that will go from the html page to the .css file to look up the class definition. In the example of the book when I find this in html

```
<p class="grassetto testorosso maiuscolo">..</p>
```

in the .css file (or in the css definition) to find the class definition in the example i think that i must try by attempts:

- attempt n 1: i will search ".testorosso.grassetto.maiuscolo" OR
  ".testorosso .grassetto .maiuscolo"? --> in any case: not found
- attempt n 2: ".grassetto.maiuscolo" --> not found
- attempt n 3: ".testorosso.maiuscolo" --> not found
- attempt n.4: ".testorosso.grassetto" --> found
- attempt n.5: ".maiuscolo" --> found

is corret? or is possible to use another more simple way to find the css definition?

and if in the attempt n 5 i find two definitions wih "maiuscolo" as this:

1) .pluto .maiuscolo {font-size: x-large}

2) .topolino .maiuscolo {font-size: xx-large}

is possible? i must select the number 1 or 2?

i'm sorry if my question don't use the correct words to define my problem... but i'm a beginner in css world,

thankyou all

Comment: Your question is not clear. I guess you want to find a rule definition in a CSS file but don't know how to search for it? If that's the case, you might never find what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes  i'm not able to find the definition of a class finded in html file as <p class="grassetto testorosso maiuscolo">..</p>.  can you  give me  a rule?

Comment: Can't you just use the Chrome's inspector that shows the rule definition and its file and line-number?

Comment: No, i can't use chrome because i must write an automatic process with a program

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to check because you can define styles in multiple ways for example

```
<div class="a">
<p class="green">Green</p>
<p>red</p>
</div>
```

to select the first p you can use either of the below techniques
.a p:nth-child(1){
color:green
}
.a .green{
color:green
}
.green{
color:green
}

but when it is

1

- 1
- 2
- 3

to select second p

div ul  li:nth-child(2) {}

for further reference you should search for css selectors